# A rather unusual bison error

Tags: c++, bison

I was teaching myself Bison and headed over to wikipedia for the same and copy-pasted the entire code from the example that was put there [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Bison ]. It compiled and works perfect. Then, I OOPed it by adding in a bit of C++. Here's is my new Parser.y file:

```
%{

#include "TypeParser.h"
#include "ParserParam.h"
#include "addition.h"

%}

%define api.pure

%left '+' TOKEN_PLUS
%left '*' TOKEN_MULTIPLY
%left '-' TOKEN_SUBTRACT
%left '/' TOKEN_DIVIDE
%left '^' TOKEN_EXP

%token TOKEN_LPAREN
%token TOKEN_RPAREN
%token TOKEN_PLUS
%token TOKEN_MULTIPLY

%token <value> TOKEN_NUMBER

%type <expression> expr

%%

input: 
        expr { ((SParserParam*)data)->expression = $1; }
        ;

expr:
      expr TOKEN_PLUS expr { $$ = new Addition($1, $2); }
    | expr TOKEN_MULTIPLY expr { $$ = new Multiplication($1, $2); }
    | expr TOKEN_SUBTRACT expr { $$ = new Addition($1, $2); }
    | expr TOKEN_DIVIDE expr { $$ = new Multiplication($1, $2); }
    | expr TOKEN_EXP expr  { $$ = new Addition($1, $2); }
    | TOKEN_LPAREN expr TOKEN_RPAREN { $$ = $2; }
    | TOKEN_NUMBER { $$ = new Value($1); }
;

%%
```

But then I keep getting the following errors:

```
Parser.y:33.52-53: $2 of `expr' has no declared type
Parser.y:34.62-63: $2 of `expr' has no declared type
Parser.y:35.56-57: $2 of `expr' has no declared type
Parser.y:36.60-61: $2 of `expr' has no declared type
Parser.y:37.52-53: $2 of `expr' has no declared type
```

How do I resolve it? I mean, what have I changed that is causing this? I haven't changed anything from the wikipedia code, the `%type%` declaration is still there [The union has the same members, with type changed from `SExpression` to `Expression`.]. All classes i.e. `Addition`, `Expression`, `Multiplication` are defined and declared. I don't think that is what is causing the problem here, but just saying.

And why exactly does it have a problem only with `$2`. Even `$1` is of type `expr`, then why do I not get any errors for `$1`?

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the rule `expr TOKEN_PLUS expr` `$1` is the first expression, **`$2` is `TOKEN_PLUS`**, and `$3` is the second expression. See the bison [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantic-Actions).

So the semantic action needs to change from your `{ $$ = new Addition($1, $2); }` to `{ $$ = new Addition($1, $3); }`.

Comment: oh... What a silly oversight. Thank you so much for pointing it out :)

Comment: I've been stumped by it myself :)